# ios CLLocationManager didUpdateToLocation Latitude and longitude migration

Tags: ios

I use this code to get the longitude and latitude.

```
    (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
         fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    self.location = newLocation;
}
```

But the longitude and latitude which i got has the excursion with the actual geographical position. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain what you are expecting?

Comment: I want to get the longitude and latitude. but it has the excursion with the actual geographical position. How could i get the accurate position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be testing the accuracy of the CLLocation object that is returned, and making sure it meets your location accuracy criteria.

```
if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 1000) {
  // Throw away this location and wait for another one as this is over 1km away
}
```

Also, the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method has been deprecated in iOS6 so you should use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` if you're targetting iOS6+.

Comment: You need to test to see if the class supports the method with the `respondsToSelector:` method - check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector: for more information.